# How to Display the categories in tree structure

Tags: magento, php

How to display all the categories in tree structure alike in a pop up window ie.) if i click the select category button in my page it should show the popup window with the tree
structured categories.i tried like this which will show all the categories in dropdown that does not look good

```
<?php                                                                            

  $categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addIsActiveFilter();
  $allcatid = array();
  $k=0;
  foreach ($categories as $c) {
     $allcatid[$k] = $c->getId();
     $k++;
  }
  $finalcat=array_shift($allcatid);
  $root= Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
?>

<select id="category" class="myinput-text required-entry widthinput" name="category" >
    <?php foreach($allcatid as $keycat){?>
         <option value="<?php echo $keycat;?>"><?php echo Mage::getModel("catalog/category")->load($keycat)->getName(); ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help you to fetch you category tree

```
<?php
$rootcatId= Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($rootcatId);
function  get_categories($categories) {
    $array= '<ul>';
    foreach($categories as $category) {
        $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId());
        $count = $cat->getProductCount();
        $array .= '<li>'.'<a href="'.Mage::getUrl($cat->getUrlPath()). '">'.         $category->getName() . "(".$count.")</a>\n";
        if($category->hasChildren()) {
            $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($category->getId());
             $array .=  get_categories($children);
            }
         $array .= '</li>';
    }
    return  $array . '</ul>';
}
echo  get_categories($categories); ?>
```

Comment: thanks DepH u helped me a lot,but i want to display all the categories and subcategories and subsubcategories... in tree structure ie.) if i click + means it should show the subcategories and - means it should hide the subcategories(expand and collapse model)

Comment: if it have helped you than do accept the answer and upvote it and if you want to expand and collapse then you have to write custom prototype/jQuery, i have implemented that but it would complex to explain here..

Comment: sorry for this man,i am not having enough reputation i joined now only in this group..so only not able to upvote u.

Answer (score 1):

**Output View**

This code is included an end-level category with product count.

[image]

**Step 1** Goto theme/layout/catalog.xml put this code in the file.

```
<reference name="left">
 <block type="catalog/navigation" name="category_list_sidebar" template="catalog/navigation/categorymenu.phtml"/>
</reference>
```

**Step 2** Goto theme/template/catalog/ and create **navigation** folder also create **categorymenu.phtml** file inside folder and put code into file.

```
<?php
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');
?>
<div class="block block-list block-categorys">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span>Category</span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ul class="category_sub">
            <?php
                if (count($_categories) > 0){

                    global $index;
                    global $data;

                    foreach($_categories as $_category){

                        $check_child_class = check_child_par($_category->getId());
                        $collaps = ($check_child_class)? "<span class='show-cat'>+</span>" : "";
                        echo "<li class='".$check_child_class."'>";
                        echo "<a href='".$_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category)."'>".$_category->getName();
                        echo " (".product_count($_category->getId()).")";
                        echo "</a>".$collaps;
                        echo check_child($_category->getId());
                        echo "</li>";

                    }
                }
            ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
    function check_child($cid){
        $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
        $_subcategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cid);
        $_subsubcategories = $_subcategory->getChildrenCategories();

        if (count($_subsubcategories) > 0){
            echo "<ul>";
            foreach($_subsubcategories as $_subcate){

                $check_child_class = check_child_par($_subcate->getId());
                $collaps = ($check_child_class)? "<span class='show-cat'>+</span>" : "";

                echo "<li class='".$check_child_class."'>";
                echo "<a href='".$_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcate)."'>".$_subcate->getName();
                echo " (".product_count($_subcate->getId()).")";
                echo "</a>".$collaps;
                echo check_child($_subcate->getId());
                echo "</li>";
            }
            echo "</ul>";
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }


    function check_child_par($cid){

        $_subcat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cid);
        $_subsubcats = $_subcat->getChildrenCategories();

        if (count($_subsubcats) > 0){
            return "parent";
        }else{
            return "";
        }
    }

    function product_count($cid){
        $products_count = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($cid)->getProductCount();
        return $products_count;
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    enter code here
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories() ?>
                <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <ul>
                        <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                            <li>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                    <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </ul>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

this will fetch all catgory and sub category,,,hope this will help you